# Append a string item to lists in a Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

For a pandas dataframe:

```
Name:        Tags:
'One'        ['tag1', 'tag3']
'Two'        []
'Three'      ['tag1']
```

How can 'tag2' be appended to the tags lists?

I have tried the following (addtag2 is another df):

```
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].astype(str) + ', ' + addtag2['Tags'].astype(str)
```

and

```
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].add(addtag2['Tags'].astype(str))
```

But they append the string outside the list eg *['tag1'], tag2 or ['tag1']tag2*

The desired output would be:

```
Name:        Tags:
'One'        ['tag1', 'tag3', 'tag2']
'Two'        ['tag2']
'Three'      ['tag1', 'tag2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance where `apply` comes handy:

```
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: x + ['tag2'])
```

Or you can do a for loop:

```
for x in df.Tags: x.append('tag2')
```

Output:

```
    Name                Tags
0    One  [tag1, tag3, tag2]
1    Two              [tag2]
2  Three        [tag1, tag2]
```

Comment: or `df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: x.append('tag2'))`

Comment: @QuangHoang it works for me; what do you mean?  `df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: x.append('tag2'))` doesn't work, but if you just call the bit after the equals sign it works (the `df` is modified in place)

Comment: @Tom That's true. My apology.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this using `append`:

```
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: x.append('tag2') or x)
```

Output:

```
    Name                Tags
0    One  [tag1, tag3, tag2]
1    Two              [tag2]
2  three        [tag1, tag2]
```